# Link multiple Authentication provider | Firebase Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm stuck in a login/registration flow with Firebase. I have a simple use case where users can register/login with email-password and login with Google. If a user is registered with email-pass and tries to log in with google with the same email id, I want to link both providers with one account. I know this can be done once the user is logged in, but I want to do it when the user is trying to log in via google, and some prompt will come up as "you already have an account, please enter your password to connect".

I have tried the scenario where the user is logged in with an email pass and trying to connect their google account.

Comment: Maybe this will help you to grasp the concept a bit: https://curity.io/resources/learn/account-linking-recipes/ It's an article explaining some general concepts behind account linking in systems. It's not a recipe that will show you how to do it with firebase, but maybe it will give you some ideas.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> If a user is registered with email-pass and tries to log in with Google with the same email id, I want to link both providers with one account.

That is happening by default. If a user signs in using email and password and later using Google provider, their account sign-in method is automatically converted to Google. Why? Because according to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users), Google is considered a trusted provider:

> - Trusted providers:
>
> > Google (for @gmail.com addresses)

And:

> Untrusted providers:
>
> > Email / Password without email verification

> In some situations, Firebase will automatically link accounts when a user signs in with different providers using the same email address.

That's because by default a user can have only one account per email address. This is done to prevent users from creating multiple accounts using the same email address with different authentication providers. However, this can be changed in the Firebase console, in the "Sign-in method" tab, inside the Authentication section.

So remember, Firebase Authentication has the concept of a preferred provider for certain email addresses, and unfortunately, there is no way to change this behavior, at least at the time I'm answering this question.

Comment: Hey Raghav. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for your input. I'm aware that default provider is automatically converted to google if they sign in with google, but if they try to sign in with email-pass 3rd time, what should happen, as there password is lost right?

Comment: If they try to sign in with email and password, right after the account was converted to Google, then they'll get an error message that says that they already have an account that uses that email address.

Comment: Hey Raghav. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Exactly that was my expectation, but currently If they try to sign in with email and password, right after the account was converted to Google, I'm getting the error which says wrong-password.

Comment: How to you get that error message? In code? On the emulator? Can you show that to us?